# Finding the Ip of a given ESSID

Tags: ip

I am interested to know if someone could actually get an ip of a user

through his/her ESSID? over a wifi network.I have been doing some research

on aircrack-ng and just want to know if this a possibilty when you know

given inetnum like 103.xxx.88.0-103.xxx.91.255,and you know the user

ESSID,then is it possible to get his/her IP?.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm interpreting your question correctly, but the only way to find out someone's privately assigned IP address on a secure wireless network is after you've associated to the access point.

1. If the wireless is not secured, just grab a packet destined for your target out of the air and the IP info will be in it.
2. If it is a wireless network with simple security, your ARP table will be populated with IPs/MACs (or if you compromise the AP you can look at its associated clients and/or DHCP lease info).
3. If it is a more secure network (clients are isolated from each other by one means or another), you may have to force a reauth on the target client and attempt to decrypt the wireless packets which will then contain IP information.

An ESS is just a collection of all BSSs of a network. For all intents and purposes, ESSID = SSID.